# JsonPathResultMatchers cannot successfully validate response

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing

Why JsonPathResultMatchers cannot successfully validate response?
**Test**

```
private static final UUID TRANSACTION_UUID_ONE = UUID.fromString("336ca9de-1583-4f39-9c67-f8380323d09d");

restBalanceMockMvc.perform(put("/api/balance")
        .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(transaction)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.transactionId").value(hasItem(TRANSACTION_UUID_ONE.toString())))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.errorCode").value(hasItem("")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.balanceVersion").value(hasItem(UPDATED_BALANCE_VERSION)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.balanceChange").value(hasItem(BALANCE_CHANGE)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.balanceAfterChange").value(hasItem(BALANCE_AFTER_CHANGE)));
```

**Response:**

```
{"username":"player1","transactionId":"336ca9de-1583-4f39-9c67-f8380323d09d","balanceChange":2,"errorCode":"","balanceVersion":1,"balanceAfterChange":5.00}
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.transactionId"
Expected: a collection containing "336ca9de-1583-4f39-9c67-f8380323d09d"
     but: was "336ca9de-1583-4f39-9c67-f8380323d09d"
Expected :a collection containing "336ca9de-1583-4f39-9c67-f8380323d09d"

Actual   :"336ca9de-1583-4f39-9c67-f8380323d09d"
```

Answer (score 0):

[JsonPathResultMatchers.value()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/JsonPathResultMatchers.html#value-org.hamcrest.Matcher-) expects a Hamcrest `Matcher` to evaluate the value.

[hasItem()](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#hasItem(T)) is defined as follows:

> Creates a matcher for `Iterables` that only matches when a single pass over the examined `Iterables` yields at least one item that is equal to the specified `item`.

`transactionId` in your JSON is a regular string rather than a collection, thus `hasItem()` cannot be used here.

Try with

```
jsonPath("$.transactionId").value(equalTo(TRANSACTION_UUID_ONE.toString()))
```

or just

```
jsonPath("$.transactionId").value(TRANSACTION_UUID_ONE.toString())
```